# Left-align right-aligned div in case there is too less space without media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I am developing the HTML/CSS of a product item detail view. In case there is enough space, I want to left-align the price and article number (.Left) and right-align two links (.Right). If there is too less space, I want to left-align all the data and display each info on a separate line. Is there any way I can achieve this without JavaScript and without media queries? As my product item detail view is within multiple nested responsive elements, I would need to add several breakpoints in order to right-align, left-align, right-align etc. which is unsexy.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="Specification">
  <div class="InfoLine">
    <div class="Left">CHF 99.90</div>
    <div class="Right">LINK1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="InfoLine">
    <div class="Left">Article-No: 31-4AB</div>
    <div class="Right">LINK2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**
Right now, my CSS looks like this:

```
.Specification .InfoLine
{
    border: 1px dotted pink;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 40px;
}

    .Specification .InfoLine .Left
    {
        border: 1px dotted green;
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 295px;
        max-width: 295px;   
    }

    .Specification .InfoLine .Right
    {
        border: 1px dotted blue;
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 185px;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

... which produces the following output:

a) Not OK: [Enough space](http://www.ppsign.ch/Temp/stack_1.jpg) - .Right box should be right-aligned (not only the box, but also the text)

b) OK: [Not enough space](http://www.ppsign.ch/Temp/stack_2.jpg) - .Right box is left-aligned below the .Left box

Comment: Can u put your website url for that product details view.

Comment: otherwise design in paint whats you need and edit it in your question?

Comment: see my CSS and screenshots above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.selectorName{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

and remove float property from the code..

Comment: inline-block is pretty useful. But this way, I cannot completely right-align the text from my .Right box.

Comment: Well, the container width must not be fixed. If possible without fixed size, probably even better.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 .Left{  
  float:left;
  }

 .Right{
  float:right;
  }
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MRzU8/1/)

Comment: that doesn't work. In case the browser-window is too small, I want that the .Right box is left-aligned.